# ansible generate *.retry file error when there are multiple plays in playbook

Tags: ansible

For example, deploy.yml is a ansible playbook. There are two plays in deploy.yml, play1 and play2.

```
$ cat deploy.yml
- hosts: nodes
  remote_user: cloud
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: play1
    copy: src=test1 dest=/root

- hosts: nodes
  remote_user: cloud
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: play2
    copy: src=test2 dest=/root

$ cat hosts
[nodes]
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.13
```

Running

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts deploy.yml
```

When play1 failed on 192.168.1.12 but success on 192.168.1.13, the deploy.retry only list 192.168.1.12 but no 192.168.1.13.

```
$ cat deploy.retry
192.168.1.12
```

Then I running

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts deploy.yml --limit @deploy.retry
```

I got a wrong result of play2 haven't be running on 192.168.1.13! Some people know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please try to use different words to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in playbok file, in facts, you have two independent playbooks in one file. I tested your setup with ansible 2.2.1.0 and second play run correctly for host without error in play1, but there can be difference in configuration.

Correct playbook format for expecting behavior is

```
- hosts: nodes
  remote_user: cloud
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: play1
    copy: src=test1 dest=/root

  - name: play2
    copy: src=test2 dest=/root
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, I just gave an example. I am using an open source k8s ansible deployment script. In this script, it use ansible role mechanism, that is, playbook has multiple plays. Is there any advice? Thank you very much!